# if $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$ for every $A \subset X$, then $f$ is continuous, using the sequence definition of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

if $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$ for every $A \subset X$, then $f: X \to Y$ is continuous, using the sequence definition of continuity. ($\overline A$ denotes the closure of $A$)

I want to prove this statement using the fact that $f:X \to Y$ is continuous iff $\{x_n\} \to x$ implies $\{f(x_n)\} \to f(x)$ (Here, $\{x_n\} = \{x_1, x_2, ...\}$ is a sequence)

This is what I currently have:

Let $\{x_n\} \to x_0$. If $\{x_n\}$ has finitely many distinct points, then $x_k = x_0$ for all large enough $k$, therefore $\{f(x_n)\} \to f(x_0)$. If it is the case that ${x_n}$ has infinitely many distinct points, $x_0$ is the only limit point of the sequence $\{x_n\}$ as a set.

Let $A = \{x_n\}$ as a set. So we get $x_0 \in\overline A \Longrightarrow f(x_0) \in f(\overline A) \Longrightarrow f(x_0) \in \overline{f(A)}$ using the hypothesis $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$.

Here's where it gets kind of confusing from me. We get that $f(x_0)$ is a limit point of $f(A)$ from above, and so there is a convergent subsequence such that $\{f(x_{n_k})\} \to f(x_0)$. However, I can't seem to prove that the sequence $f(x_n)$ itself converges without being circular. Could anyone improve upon this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\bigl(f(x_n)\bigr)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ does *not* converge to $f(x_0)$. Then for some $\varepsilon>0$, there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ of $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that$$(\forall k\in\Bbb N):D\bigl(f(x_{n_k}),f(x_0)\bigr)\geqslant 0.$$But $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{n_k}=x_0$ and it follows then from what you proved that $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ has a subsequence such that its images converges to $f(x_0)$. So, you reach a contradiction.